# Whether I will receive an email once people answer my question

Tags: discussion

I just want to confirm how the process of asking a question works.

- Whether I will receive an email once people answer my question?
- Could I remove my questions after posting it?

Comment: You can change your email preferences in your settings page. For example `https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/{Your User ID}`. As for the latter, why would you want to delete it after posting it? That doesn't help the site grow.

Comment: "Could I remove my questions after posting it?" You might want to read through the help center again. Removing a question when you got what you wanted isn't exactly the point of [so].

Comment: I think that as long as your question isn't answered you can delete it yourself.

Comment: "Could I remove my questions after posting it?" - Can you remove it, only if it meets the requirements, but you should avoid deleting your question. Asking a question then deleting your question is not behavior we encourage it, asking a question then deleting it (before or after an answer is submitted), is extremely negative and a great way to be question banned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Whether I will receive an email once people answer my question?

That depends on your settings, which you can find in Settings -> Edit Email Settings -> Your Communities. You have an option to chose your notification periods for your Inbox: Off, 3 Hours, Daily or Weekly. You will then get emails appropriately for your choice.

You will always get notified immediately in your inbox on the site though; it is recommended you keep an eye on this for a period of time after asking a question. Not answering comments that ask for clarification, or advise how you can improve the question promptly can often result in users downvoting and/or voting to close your question. As an answerer it is *very* frustrating to ask for clarification and not get an answer until the following day when you comment within minutes of the question being asked. You will likely find users won't have interest after that amount of time.

> Could I remove my questions after posting it?

Why would want to do this? Stack Overflow is a Q&A website for everyone, not a free coding/consultancy service for you. If you want to ask a question, get an answer, and then hide it from the community, then you are going to have a very poor experience here. If you don't want the answers you get shared, then hire someone one and ensure that part of the contract states that the work they do belongs to the business you work for. All work here is licenced under [cc by-sa](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), including your questions, so if you are going to be using the solutions you get here, deleting it would not be helpful in the citations you are *required* to use.

Of course, if your question is poorly received you may feel you want to delete it, but ideally you should be using the edit feature first to improve it; deleting should be a last resort.